# Tomcat Error: Embedded H2 DB Read-Only

Tags: java, tomcat, h2, readonly

I am getting the following error in my tomcat logs when trying to start an app that uses an `embedded h2.db` file:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The database is read only**; SQL statement:<br>
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '192.168.122.1 (192.168.122.1)', LOCKGRANTED = '2017-10-19 17:06:08.499' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE [90097-175]<br>
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:138)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.checkWritingAllowed(Database.java:1784)
        at org.h2.table.Table.checkWritingAllowed(Table.java:1082)
        at org.h2.engine.User.hasRight(User.java:114)
        at org.h2.engine.User.checkRight(User.java:100)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Update.update(Update.java:87)
```

As you can see it can't run the update statement to get a lock on the DB.

**To troubleshoot:** 
1. I opened an h2 shell to run and connect to the h2 db directly:

```
sudo java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:file:/usr/share/tomcat/ellucianmobile/banner-mobileserver/banner-mobileserver-prodD" -driver "org.h2.Driver" -user "sa" -password ""
```

2. I then listed out the tables:

   ```
   sql> SHOW TABLES; 
   TABLE_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA  
   BUILDING_DOMAIN | PUBLIC 
   CALENDAR | PUBLIC 
   CAMPUS_DOMAIN | PUBLIC  
   CATEGORY | PUBLIC 
   CONFIGURATION_DOMAIN | PUBLIC 
   DATABASECHANGELOG | PUBLIC 
   DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK | PUBLIC 
   ENTRY_CACHE | PUBLIC 
   ENTRY_CACHE_LINK | PUBLIC  
   ENTRY_DOMAIN | PUBLIC 
   EVENT | PUBLIC 
   EVENT_CATEGORIES | PUBLIC  
   FEED_CACHE | PUBLIC 
   FEED_CACHE_LINK | PUBLIC  
   MS_DEVICE | PUBLIC 
   MS_DEVICEUSER | PUBLIC 
   MS_NMESSAGE | PUBLIC 
   MS_NOTIFICATION | PUBLIC 
   MS_NOT_DEL_REC_DOMAIN | PUBLIC  
   MS_NSTATUS | PUBLIC 
   MS_RECIPIENT | PUBLIC 
   MS_RECIPIENT_STATUSES | PUBLIC  
   NOTIFICATION_DELIVERY_DOMAIN | PUBLIC  
   NUMBERS_DOMAIN | PUBLIC 
   REGISTRATION_CART | PUBLIC 
   SYSTEM_DATA_DOMAIN | PUBLIC 
   (26 rows, 28 ms)
   ```
3. I can SELECT rows from a given table: 
   (As you can see below locked is set to FALSE)

   ```
   sql> SELECT * FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;
   ID | LOCKED | LOCKGRANTED | LOCKEDBY 
   1 | FALSE | null | null
   (1 row, 1 ms)
   ```
4. Since reading worked I tried to write to the DB:

   ```
   sql> UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=FALSE, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1; 

   Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The database is read only;
   ```

The same error that tomcat is getting when it tries to run an UPDATE to get a lock.

**What can I do to make the h2 db available for read AND write by default?**

Comment: Does your user have write permission to that path?

Comment: In my troubleshooting I am using sudo to run the command and I am able to view the contents of the H2 DB as demonstrated above.  Tomcat definitely has access as the file is located in an sub-directory of tomcat with the following permissions: rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   321536 Oct 20 00:22 banner-mobileserver-prodD.h2.db

Comment: sudo to what account?

Comment: I am using sudo without specifying a user which I believe defaults to root in Red Hat Enterprise when running a command requiring elevated permissions.

Comment: It does (everywhere). I don't remember about Tomcat specifically offhand, but I know that many servers will drop privileges if they're started as root.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Windows server running Tomcat as a service. By default it was running as the LOCAL_SERVICE account which did not have write permission to the db folder. You can fix this by either granting modify permission to the db folder for the LOCAL_SERVICE account, or by changing the service account to LOCAL_SYSTEM.

Answer (score -1):

Adding this worked for me

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
class ApplicationConfig {
}
```